# How do I write a hover code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

when i made a button and ineeded it to hover i made the code and tried to run it ,it didn't run ,while when i tried  to run it in http://jsfiddle.net/4z2zq/169/ it runs perfectly plz help!!

code :

html :

```
<div type="button" id="login">Login</div>
```

css:

```
#login{
position: absolute;
top: 42px;
left: 1202px;
width: 63px;
height: 19px;
background-color: #2799b6;
text-align: center;
font-family: corbel;
border-radius:20px;
color:#FFF;
font-size:15px;

    }
```

js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$(function() {
$('#login').hover(function() { 
$(this).fadeOut(); 
}, function() { 
$(this).fadeIn(); 
});
});
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by you need the button to hover? Do you mean you want to apply an effect whenever someone hovers over the button? Or something different?

Comment: As its working in fiddle, Make sure jQuery is correctly imported in your code

Comment: What does your JavaScript error console report? What does it report if you add `console.log` statements throughout your code or if you use a debugger to see which lines are reached?

Comment: If you want a button, use a `<button>`, not a `<div>`. If you want a hover style, then use CSS, not JavaScript.

Comment: div type = button? Mindfudge.

Comment: @Quentin He's obviously wanting an animated hover effect. Are you telling him to use CSS3 animations?

Comment: @h2ooooooo — Transitions. Yes.

Comment: @Quentin Then you're also telling him to build software that doesn't support anything less than IE 10 (`~37%` market share).

Comment: @h2ooooooo — and falling … for a cosmetic effect. And that market share estimate looks wrong.

Comment: Exceuse me, have you just given an example of WORKING code and asked why it doesn't work in a context that you completely omitted? There is no valid answer to such a question. Please give additional information before hoping to get an answer. Does the JS console give any feedback? Do you have jQuery imported in your code?

Comment: @Quentin You're more than welcome to look up the market share of IE6 + IE7 + IE8 + IE9 in 2014. :-) I know my customers wouldn't be too happy if I told them that only the newest browsers can show the animation they so badly wanted on their page ("but it works on HER website!!!").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use CSS (3 if you want animation)?

```
#login{
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  left: 1202px;
  width: 63px;
  height: 19px;
  background-color: #2799b6;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: corbel;
  border-radius:20px;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:15px;
  opacity:1;
  -moz-transition:    opacity .5s;
  -o-transition:      opacity .5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition:         opacity .5s;
}
#login:hover{
  opacity:0;
  -moz-transition:    opacity .5s;
  -o-transition:      opacity .5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
  transition:         opacity .5s;
}
```

I have no idea why you would want a button/element to disappear on mouse over but hey!

if you just want an answer to your original question:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#login').hover(function(){$(this).fadeOut()},function(){$(this).fadeIn()});

});
```

problem being, fadeOut makes the item properly hidden, therefore it will automatically reappear as you mouse out when it vanishes.....

Comment: css3 opacity (and all % values) work in decimal - so if you are using my css solution above, change 
    #login:hover{
      opacity:0;
    ....

to

    #login:hover{
      opacity:.5;
    ....

which will make it semi opaque

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your fiddle to use css transitions http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/4z2zq/182/

```
#login{
position: absolute;
top: 42px;
/* left: 1202px; *//* this is commented out for debugging */
width: 63px;
height: 19px;
background-color: #2799b6;
text-align: center;
font-family: corbel;
border-radius:20px;
color:#FFF;
font-size:15px;

opacity:1;

-webkit-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
-moz-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
 -o-transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
    transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.000, 0.580, 1.000); 
}


#login:hover {
opacity: 0.3;
}
```

Comment: If you only want to lower opacity then set opacity: 0.3 or so.

Answer (score -2):

There is no need for the second anonymous function. Try:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#login').hover(function() { 
$(this).fadeOut(); 
}, function() { 
$(this).fadeIn(); 
});
});
</script>
```

If this doesn't work you haven't referenced jQuery correctly. In the head section of your webpage you need to type:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What you have changed?

Comment: While that is true, it doesn't address the problem.

Comment: This is just tidying up your code, if it doesn't work for you, you haven't referenced jquery properly in your page.

Comment: Answer edited. Check again for jQuery referencing.